# SP2-0552: Bind variable "V_COUNT" not declared

Tags: plsql

```
SQL> declare
     CURSOR mycur  is  select  owner ,table_name from dba_tables where  owner in ('IBROKERREPORT','FIXGATEWAYBLP','ITRADESYS','EMUSER','SYSUCM','DBMON','ICBCMFIX','IBROKERACCESS');
     v_owner   VARCHAR2(128);
     v_count   number(10);
     v_table_name  VARCHAR2(128);
     sql_cmd_select  varchar(2000);
     sql_cmd_insert  varchar(2000);
begin
                open mycur;
                  loop
                         fetch mycur into v_owner,v_table_name;
       exit when mycur%notfound;
       sql_cmd_select:='select count(1) from '||v_owner||'.'||v_table_name;
       execute immediate  sql_cmd_select into  v_count;
       sql_cmd_insert :='insert into dbmon.table_cut values (:table_name ,:owner,:cnt)';
       execute immediate  sql_cmd_insert using :v_table_name,:v_owner,:v_count ;
       commit ;
       end loop;
end ;  /



SP2-0552: Bind variable "V_COUNT" not declared.
SQL>
```

Comment: Angus, after you paste something into your post that you want to appear verbatim (e.g., code), then you select what you pasted and then click the editor's `{}` button. Easy peasy.

Comment: Your `execute immediate`'s using clause should be `using v_table_name, v_owner, v_count`.

Comment: `:v_count` <> `v_count`. By the way, formatting your code makes it a lot easier to understand and fix. Plus it's kind of a programming tradition.